# Subsetting by coord in xarray

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I have a netCDF file that I opened using xarray. It has the foll. coords:

```
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float32 89.875 89.625 89.375 89.125 88.875 88.625 88.375 ...
  * lon      (lon) float32 -179.875 -179.625 -179.375 -179.125 -178.875 ...
  * time     (time) int32 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 ...
```

How can I subset it so that time starts from 2010 instead of 2005 (lat and lon remain the same)? I want an xarray solution only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.sel` method should work, e.g., `ds.sel(time=slice(2010, None))`. See [the docs](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/indexing.html) for more details.

Comment: thanks @shoyer, is ds.sel(time=(hndl_nc.time >= 2010)) ok too? It seems to work ok. Here hndl_nc is handle to netCDF file

Comment: Yes, that also works. In some cases, `slice` can be more efficient (not requiring a memory copy), which is why I suggested it that way. But it only works if the index is monotonic.