# crop xarray unstructured mesh by geographic extension

Tags: geospatial, mesh, python-xarray

### The problem

Hi all,
I am working with an unstructured triangular mesh in Xarray and I have problems cropping it by spatial extent in an efficient way. My xarray dims and coordinates are as follows:

```
Dimensions:
time: 25, nMesh2D_face: 149596, max_nMesh2D_face_nodes: 3, nMesh2D_node: 77059

Coordinates:
time(time)datetime64[ns]                 2022-01-01 ... 2022-01-01T04:00:00
Mesh2D_node_x(nMesh2D_node)float64      -81.54 -81.54 ... -81.53 -81.55
Mesh2D_node_y(nMesh2D_node)float64       30.41 30.41 30.41 ... 30.4 30.4
Mesh2D_face_x(nMesh2D_face)float32       ...
Mesh2D_face_y(nMesh2D_face)float32       ...
```

**I am trying to crop this efficiently by x and y values.**

### What have I tried

The common solution for other types of data is the `.sel()` function (see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41783216/subsetting-by-coord-in-xarray) or [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/353698/how-to-clip-an-xarray-to-a-smaller-extent-given-the-lat-lon-coordinates), as in:

```
cropped_data = data.sel(Mesh2D_node_x=slice(min_x, max_x), Mesh2D_node_x=slice(min_y, max_y))
```

but this doesn't work in my case because *Mesh2D_node_x* and *Mesh2D_node_y* are just coordinates and not dimensions, but my dimension do not have geographic coordinates themselves, so this throws an error when I try to run it.
I have also tried to use the .where() such as :

```
mask_x = (data.Mesh2D_node_x >= xmin) & (data.Mesh2D_node_x <= xmax)
mask_y = (data.Mesh2D_node_y >= ymin) & (data.Mesh2D_node_y <= ymax)

masked_data = data.where(mask_x & mask_y, drop=True)
```

but this loads the whole dataset in memory and causes memory issues aside form being extremely inefficient.

I would try RioXarray but it seems it doesn't work for unstructured mesh before translating to grid which makes very inefficient.

So what are my options here, is there something else I should try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bets solution I found was to crop the vertex-face layer. Once you eliminate your vertex outside the bounding box from there, the other layers get cropped as well